# Uploading a bootstrap application using Heroku - Issue with start script/procfile

Tags: node.js, heroku

In short, I have a bootstrap website that uses webpack to compile all of my html/css/scss/js together into a bundle.js file, which allows me to simply run the index.html file in order to locally host my website. I'm trying to deploy it to heroku, but I really cannot figure out the start script necessary to get it up and running. Here is my file structure:
[Link to imgur file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj0Yn.png)

The command I use to open my website is either ./dist/index.html or start dist/index.html. Both work, but do not work as a Heroku start command in my package.json. This is the error message I always receive:

```
2020-08-23T18:34:22.171971+00:00 app[web.1]: > bootstrap-npm-webpack@1.0.0 start /app
2020-08-23T18:34:22.171971+00:00 app[web.1]: > start dist/index.html
2020-08-23T18:34:22.171972+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-23T18:34:22.181445+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: start: not found
2020-08-23T18:34:22.186223+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-23T18:34:22.186436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-08-23T18:34:22.186580+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-08-23T18:34:22.186749+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-08-23T18:34:22.188732+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! bootstrap-npm-webpack@1.0.0 start: `start 
dist/index.html`
2020-08-23T18:34:22.188771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-08-23T18:34:22.188879+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-08-23T18:34:22.188987+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap-npm-webpack@1.0.0 start 
script.
2020-08-23T18:34:22.189080+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There 
is likely additional logging output above.    
2020-08-23T18:34:22.215757+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-23T18:34:22.215946+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-23T18:34:22.216042+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-23T18_34_22_190Z- 
debug.log
2020-08-23T18:34:22.270259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-23T18:34:22.302093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-23T18:42:02.298343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/" host=rocky-ravine-98224.herokuapp.com request_id=0b9453c6-af45-4e81-9527-d2026c8bf36d 
fwd="76.10.13.86" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-23T18:42:02.708939+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-ravine-98224.herokuapp.com request_id=e2f0b57f-c88b-4ae4-b1c2- 
2665ef59dd5c fwd="76.10.13.86" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "bootstrap-npm-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "start dist/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "exports-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "harp": "^0.32.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ];
              }
            }
          },
          {
            // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I've tried using different start scripts like

```
./dist/index.html //(works in command line, but heroku says "permission denied")
```

or

```
node src/app.js
```

or

```
node dist/bundle.js
```

Neither of which yield anything positive.

The ultimate question I have here is: What does my start script need to be to get my website to deploy?
I've been stuck on this for days and I would sincerely appreciate your help.

**edit**: my solution was to start learning express. Although I haven't gotten my website completely up yet because of a routing problem, changing my directories and creating a server.js file that uses express.static to route the path to a client folder has solved my issue of what start script to run, as I can now just run `node server.js`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the file name in your root dir, which you call node to start your app. For example, I start my app locally by `node app.js`, then I add `"start": "node app.js"` in my package.json file to solve this err. Hope this helpful :)